# Install Tensorflow Lite C++ Api in Ubuntu for Google Coral API

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

I'm trying to install Tensorflow Lite C ++ Api in order to use Google Coral with C ++ API in an embedded board that is not raspberry py. I can't generate the tensorflow-lite.so library and I'm not very expert on bazel. Can anyone guide me in creating the library? Thank you

Comment: Have you gone though https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64 ?

Answer (score 0):

Detailed instructions to build the TFLite library for ARM64 are available at : https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64

Comment: These instructions are for arm cpus, isn't it possible to run tensorflow light on an intel plateform for development before moving the code to a raspberry pi?